# Render blob from servlet in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, blob

I am trying to get a byte array from my database through the GetImage servlet,
then push the array through the response and in the ImgGet() function render the blob as an image and make it appear on a certain element.
I dont get any errors, just the photo is broken sprite(chrome), like it fails to read the resource or sth.
The `getPhotoBlobWithID` function returns the correct byte array.

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        boolean metadata = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("metadata"));

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("image"));

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            try {
                if ( metadata ){

                    String imgMeta = db.PhotosDB.getPhotoMetadataWithID(id).toString();
                    //out.println(imgMeta);

                }
                else{

                    String imgBlob = Arrays.toString(db.PhotosDB.getPhotoBlobWithID(id));

                    byte[] picBytes = db.PhotosDB.getPhotoBlobWithID(id);


                    out.write(picBytes);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GetImageCollection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }   

}
```

Javascript:

```
function ImgGet(id){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("CollectionContainer");
    var elem = document.createElement("img");



    //Change request parameters for desired result
    xhr.open("GET", "GetImage?image="+id+"&metadata=false" ,true);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onload = function () {


    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        //var base64data;
        var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;

        //var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: "image/png"});
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

        reader.onload = function() {
            base64data = reader.result;                
            var newimg = document.createElement("img");
            newimg.setAttribute("src",base64data);
            document.getElementById("CollectionContainer").appendChild(newimg);
        };

    } 
    else{
        alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get it correct you are requesting an image as raw byte stream which you later make it into a `Blob` and read that using `Filereader` , the reason why it shows up as an broken image (assuming you get correct response) might be due to not setting a correct value for the [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) header which tells the server what type of data it's supposed to send, by default this would be "DOMString which is UTF-16 so all bytes are treated as UTF-16 and decoded that way .Note that this value is actually for browser so that it could decode correctly

To make it work you would need to set this header before you `send()` ajax request.You can either use

`xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';`

or `xhr.responseType = 'blob';`

Comment: Yes, i didnt notice that. Thank you.